# A field related with more than a table

Tags: mysql, database

My database for my website is little complicated.

I have 6 tables (Users, Ads, Categories, PropertiesOfVehicule, PropertiesOfHouses, PropertiesOfClothes).

Let me explain it a little:

The website is a classified ads site, so there's a lot of ads. So, I made two FK one for the category and an other for the user's id.

But I created 3 more tables for properties, so if the ad belong to vehicle category so he has its own properties like (color, miles, speed..) so logically it has to be joined with PropertiesOfVehicule table! But if there's an other ad belong to Clothes category, I have to joined with PropertiesOfClothes table!!

How to make that? Join a column (Propertyid) with several tables?!
An other question, I read I book that he used FK to reference the Id of a category, and he used the inner join to select and echo the data! But there's no relationships!

So I'm confused!

P.S. if there's someone can help me, it would be a big pleasure to discuss on this topic in private.

Answer (score 0):

-From what i understood, the table 'Ad' is your main table. You could reference the primary key of the 'Ad' table in 'Users' and 'Catogories'. Im assuming all your relationships between the tables 'ad-user', 'ad-category' as one-one.

-Regarding the property related tables,you could have a single table called 'PROPERTIES' and reference the primary key of 'Ad' in it.

-Have the columns as 'PROPERTY', 'VALUE' in the 'PROPERTIES' table. And give the name of properties like 'color','speed','miles' as values under 'PROPERTY' column and their value in 'VALUES' column.

-By this,  you can just use the primary key of 'Ad' table to join with all other tables and retrieve the required information.

Comment: Thanks, but about the tables of properties , let me explained well. I.e : Vehicle Properties : Color , Speed , miles .. ! and there's an other tables of clothes properties with 3 columns : id, color, size ! I don't think one table of properties may solve the problem .

Comment: You are going to use an unique id to retrieve the set of properties.  So I think that will not be a problem.  To avoid confusion you can name the property appended with some unique string like 'color_vehicle' ,'color_cloth'. Note: these are not columns. But values under 'NAME' column in single properties table.

Answer (score 0):

Now , I finished my database design , with deleting all the properties tables, and using one column for properties instead! in this field (longtext) will be filled with an array with the values of each item , so I think it's better .
Thanks anyway .